# Mutual Information involving two matrix states

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, numerics

I basically retrieved the following technique of evaluating the mutual information involving two matrices from this site at 
http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/People/BRomeny/Courses/8C080/default.htm
The original code was written for image-processing, but could perhaps apply to other areas as well.

Mutual Information = H(A)+H(B)-H(AB), where H(X) is the entropy of X

My question: How to do you generalize this to apply to a matrix of arbitrary elements (including decimals less than 1, and negative numbers)? Can this also be extended to matrix of any dimension (i.e. larger than 2?).

The program follows as:

```
imA = ({
   {0, 1, 3, 0},
   {0, 0, 2, 5},
   {3, 2, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 3, 4}
  }); 

imB = ({
   {1, 1, 0, 4},
   {3, 0, 4, 5},
   {0, 0, 2, 5},
   {0, 1, 4, 5}
  }); 

histogramA = BinCounts[Flatten[imA], {0, 6, 1}]
hA = Total[-(histogramA/nA) Log[histogramA/nA]] // N
nA = Total[histogramA]

histogramB = BinCounts[Flatten[imB], {0, 6, 1}];
nB = Total[histogramB];
hB = Total[-(histogramB/nB) Log[histogramB/nB]] // N
imAB = Transpose[{imA, imB}, {3, 1, 2}]
histogramAB = BinCounts[Flatten[imAB, 1], {0, 6, 1}, {0, 6, 1}];
nAB = Total[histogramAB, 2];
fh = Flatten[histogramAB]
fh2 = DeleteCases[fh, 0]
hAB = Total[-(fh2/nAB) Log[fh2/nAB]] // N
MI = hA + hB - hAB
```

Comment: Simplest thing might be to normalize the data so it all lies between (say) 0 and 255, quantize to integers, then apply the method you have.

Comment: How about normalizing a matrix `a` by: `Round[255*a/(Max[Max[a]] - Min[Min[a]])]`

Comment: I used imA = Partition[Normalize[Flatten[matA]], 4] imB = Partition[Normalize[Flatten[matB]], 4] but there appears to be some changes needed in BinCounts and so no output from this amendment.

Comment: This is probably the best way forward: Suppose we have imA = Flatten[({ {0.25, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.25, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.25, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.25} })]                             imB = Flatten[({ {0.25, -0.01, 0, 0}, {-0.01, 0.25, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.25, -0.05}, {0, 0, -0.05, 0.25} })]                                                  N[Entropy[imA]] N[Entropy[imB]] Entropy[imA] + Entropy[imB] - Statistics`Library`NConditionalEntropy[imA, imB] is the required answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutual Info= H(A) - NConditionalEntropy(A,B) as described above will yield the answer.

Comment: imA = Flatten[({
     {0.25, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0.25, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0.25, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0.25}
    })];                                                   N[Entropy[imA] + Entropy[imB] - 
  Entropy[Flatten[TensorProduct[imA, imB]]]]  (*negative MI avoided using this approach *)

Comment: thils = beautiful code. Compact and elegant.

Comment: Could you please give the MMA code for the MI you calculated? I cannot find `NConditionalEntropy` in Mathematica. I need to calculate MI across various input-output tables in Economics.